# avoid automatic convertion to float python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following parameters:

```
param_grid = dict(par1 = [0.1, 1.1, 1.2], 
                  par2 = [3, 4, 5], 
                  par3 = [6, 7, 8])
```

I would like to create a table with all the possible combination of parameters. I tried with the following code

```
hyperParamSpace = pd.DataFrame([row for row in itertools.product(*param_grid.values())], 
                               columns=param_grid.keys())
```

When I take the first combination with
`hyperParamSpace.iloc[1]` it converts all the parameters in floats:

```
par3    6.0
par2    3.0
par1    1.1
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

How can I keep the integer as integer type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it does that is because each column of the `DataFrame` in `pandas` is essentially a `numpy` array. The elements of the array must be all of the same type, otherwise it loses a lot of its computational advantages. Therefore, if one of the elements in a column is a float, it will automatically convert all of the elements to floats.

You can control `dtype` of the array, and by extension, the `DataFrame`, manually and set it to `int`, but you will lose your floats in this case.

However, in your example elements of the columns with ints are actually of the type `int64` (you can verify it by running `hyperParamSpace.par2.dtype`), but when you slice a row with `iloc`, it converts them to floats in the output, because of the same principle: to create an array, where all elements have same type.

What you can do to avoid the conversion is to specify `dtype` of your `DataFrame` as `object`:

```
hyperParamSpace = pd.DataFrame([row for row in itertools.product(*param_grid.values())],
                                columns=param_grid.keys(), dtype=object)
```

This will drastically decrease the efficiency, but since your parameter table is small, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! how can I extract the first row maintaining the type?

Comment: well, you can't slice with with any pandas tools, because it will automatically create a `Series` and convert it to float. you'd have to make some kind of iteration through the elements of the row and then put them in a list, which is very ugly and inefficient. are you sure you absolutely must have them as integers? I added some code to the answer which will help you create a list with integers and floats.

Comment: yep... I need to pass them as paramenter of a classifier that accepts specific types..

Comment: there is probably a better solution, but the code in the answer should get you there nonetheless. (P.S. don't forget to accept the answer if it settles your question.)

Comment: ok, I actually found another solution that is better. I added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect